# given Integer n and Double x. Calculate: sin x + sinsin x +...+sinsin...sinx. Where n— number of sin

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I wrote :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String sn = reader.readLine();
            String sx = reader.readLine();

            int n = Integer.parseInt(sn);
            double x = Double.parseDouble(sx);

            double sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                x = Math.sin(x);
                sum += x;
            }

            System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

But lecturer said, that this code wrong

Comment: OK, well... does it give the right answer for `n = 1`, `n = 2`, `n = 3` etc? It's easy enough to check with a calculator. (Assuming he means that the calculation is incorrect)

Comment: And did he actually say just "this code is wrong"? That is a terrible way to report a bug. There are a number of ways this code could be wrong: getting the values, the calculation, the exception handling, the resource handling...

Comment: You're adding when you should be multiplying i think.

Comment: If the question was "write code that calculates [something about x and n], you'd better provide a *function* which calculates it. And a main() which calls it, and prints the results. Separation of responsibilities.

Comment: Okay so your calculation is not correct you are just adding `sin(x)` together `n` times.

Comment: @3kings : he's not, because of the `x = Math.sin(x);` line

Comment: have you considered that you may be dealing with degrees as opposed to radians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner body of your code, the algorithm part which actually computes the answer is correct.

You can check that part using an interactive Haskell session with ghci (which makes things like repeated function invocation a lot more simple to work with).

E.g. using Haskell the computation can be reduced to this: `(\x n -> sum . tail . take (n+1) $ iterate sin x) 0.5 2`, which calculates for `x = 0.5` and `n = 2` and produces **0.9406950936373837**

But it may be you need to re-read the problem. Is the input supposed to be in degrees instead of radians? Given the pattern of repeated function application, maybe the output is supposed to be `x + sin(x) + ...`, in which case the Haskell code for verification purposes would be:

`(\x n -> sum . take n $ iterate sin x)` and the same example of `x = 0.5` and `n = 2` would yield **0.979425538604203**

Futhermore you have a problem in your solution: what if there is no input? What if there is only one line? You assume you will always get 2 lines, but... that may not be the case. You have no error handling whatsoever.

Also, maybe the teacher demands you put your algorithm of the sum of repeated sinuses inside a function of its own?

Answer (score 0):

It’s clear that your answer is the *sum* of `n` terms **where** the`i`th term has a nested chain of `i` sines.

Here’s the code that does that. Note how clear everything is made by the use of proper variable names and reasoning about the structure of the solution.

```
class Potato
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double x = 0.5;
        int n = 2;

        double sum = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            double term = x;
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                term = Math.sin(term);
            sum += term;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

For the particular values that I have here, the sequence is

`sin(0.5) + sin(sin(0.5)) ==> 0.9406950936373837`

As also confirmed manually using this python snippet:

```
>>> sin(0.5) + sin(sin(0.5))
0.9406950936373837
```

**However**, your code is correct as well, and more efficient, avoiding repeated calculations.

To see why this is true:

You can write `term[i]` as `sin(term[i-1])`

And the desired answer is `sum(term)`, which is exactly what you calculate.

Comment: That's terrible code because you compute the same term many times.  Leading to n²/2 calls to sin to compute tu sum of n terms.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Not true at all

Comment: @michelsnowden in the given program, sin(x) is computed 5 times, sin(sin(x)) 4 times, sin(sin(sin(x))) 3 times etc.

Comment: @MichelBillaud I mean that doesn't make it terrible

Comment: @MichelBillaud you are correct, results may be memoised for efficiency, but in my opinion, in this form, it is really easy to understand, and to prove correctness of.

Comment: The correctness proof is the same with a loop invariant which states that  
-- x contains the i-th iterate of the  initial value of x, 
-- and the sum variable holds the the sum of the i first iterates.
The shorter the code, the simpler the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this if you want to be a little more efficient:

```
public static double sum(double x, int n) {
    assert n >= 1;
    double sum = 0;
    double term = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        term = Math.sin(term);
        sum = sum + term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void test() {
    double x = Math.PI / 2;

    System.out.println(sum(x, 1) + " " + Math.sin(x));
    System.out.println(sum(x, 2) + " " + (Math.sin(x) + Math.sin(Math.sin(x))));
    System.out.println(sum(x, 3) + " " + (Math.sin(x) + Math.sin(Math.sin(x)) + Math.sin(Math.sin(Math.sin(x)))));
}
```

Output from test (for both versions):

```
1.0 1.0
1.8414709848078965 1.8414709848078965
2.5870951264734545 2.5870951264734545
```

Recursive version

```
public static double sum(double x, double n) {
    return sum(x, n, Math.sin(x));
}

public static double sum(double x, double n, double term) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return term + sum(x, n - 1, Math.sin(term));
}
```